# disable all checkboxes from ListView after one selected

Tags: java, android, listview

In `MainActivity` I have `ListView` with custom single choice `Checkboxes` each item has one checkbox and they are set to List by Custom Adapter class. If  user checked one then pop up dialog  with choice confirmation and after accept all checkboxes should be disabled but for now only one from selected row is disabled. How can I disable all and block user possibility to change choice ?

`Adapter`

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {


    SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
    private List<CustomClass> customList;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int selectedPosition = -1;
    private Dialog dialog;


    public CustomAdapter(Context _context, List<CustomClass> _customList) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(_context);
        this.customList = _CustomList;
        this.context = _context;
        mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(customList.size());
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return customList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

       CustomClass customClass = customList.get(i);

        if (view == null)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);


        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        checkBox.setTag(i);
        checkBox.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(i, false));
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        checkBox.setChecked(false);

        if (i == selectedPosition) {
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }

        checkBox.setOnClickListener(onStateChangedListener(checkBox, i));


        name.setText(customClass.getName());


        return view;

    }

    private View.OnClickListener onStateChangedListener(final CheckBox checkBox, final int position) {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    selectedPosition = position;

                    dialog =  new Dialog(context);
                    dialog.setTitle("Accept");
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_accept);
                    dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {

                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();

                    Button btnAccept = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnVote);

                    btnAccept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            checkBox.setEnabled(false);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });


                } else {
                    selectedPosition = -1;

                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }


    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


        mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
        notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
```

CustomClass:

```
    public class CustomClass{

    String name;

    public CustomClass(){}

    public CustomClass(String name){
    this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){return name;}
    public void setName(String name){this.name = name;}

}
```

`MainActivity` have only set `ListView` and `Adapter`

Answer (score 2):

Include all the check boxes inside a group so that only one check box can be selected .

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById("R.id.list");
for(int x = 0; x < list.getItems.length(); x++){ list.items.get(x).setEnabled(false);}
```

Not sure but maybe something like this. Worth a try?

Answer (score 0):

In Checkbox change listener

```
private int selectedPosition = 0;

   private View.OnClickListener onStateChangedListener(final CheckBox checkBox, final int position) {
            return new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                        customClass.setSelected(true);
                        customList.get(selectedPosition).setSelected(false);
                        selectedPosition = position;

                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            };
```

in `Getview()`

```
if(customClass.getSelected()){
        checkBox.setEnable(true);
    }else{
        checkBox.setEnable(false);
    }
```